# Jenkins parameterized trigger plugin : launch scripts in order

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

how can I tell Jenkins to run my scripts in order : run script1, if script1 is finished run script2 and same for script3.
In my image, Jenkins doesn't run them in order (script3 can be launched first..).
I am using parameterized trigger plugin because each script needs parameters.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcFHb.png

Comment: Can you trigger script1 from your main project and then script2 from script1, then script3 from script2?

Comment: If I do that, I won't be able to pass predefined parameters :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a Pipeline, you can call the jobs serially from your "main" pipeline and pass parameters to each job.

Taken from [this example](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/221400287-How-to-pass-parameter-to-downstream-job-in-Pipeline-job):

```
node {
    paramAValue = "paramAValue"
    paramBValue = "paramBValue"
    build job: 'script1', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ParamA', value: paramAValue], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ParamB', value: paramBValue]]
    build job: 'script2', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ParamA', value: paramAValue], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ParamB', value: paramBValue]]
    build job: 'script3', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ParamA', value: paramAValue], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ParamB', value: paramBValue]]
}
```

To ensure that one completes before another runs, you could put them in different stages.